# error with struts jasperreports plugin and jasper result type

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

I'm trying use struts2-jasperreports plugin but getting an error with the type result:

> Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed Unable to load configuration.
>   - [unknown location]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: The Result type
>   [jasper] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class
>   Actions.GenerarReportesAction] or determined by the file extension or
>   is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could
>   not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package
>   [Actions#convention-default#] - [unknown location]    at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultConfig(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:438)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createFromAnnotations(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.build(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.createActionConfig(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:891)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:345)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:245)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
>     ... 45 more

I googled how to solve it but nothing, i supposed having the correct configuration but maybe somebody can see my mistakes, please help me!!

Im using struts2 jasperreports and annotations. My struts.xml

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default, jasperreports-default">
            <result-types> 
           <result-type name="jasper" class="org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult" /> 
   </result-types>  
   </package>
```

The action file

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;


public class GenerarReportesAction extends ActionSupport {
private Map<String,Object> params;
private int numsol;


       @Action(value = "imprimirVale", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", type="jasper", 
            params={"location","/Reportes/ValeAlmacen.jasper"," format", "PDF", "reportParameters","%{params}","documentName","vale_almacen.pdf"})})
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        try {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                    "Reportes/ValeAlmacen.jrxml",
                    "Reportes/ValeAlmacen.jasper");
            params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            URL img = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../../img/IQFALOGO.jpg");
            params.put("img",img.toString() );

           params.put("numsol",numsol);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the answer:

> Result annotation on the class [class Actions.GenerarReportesAction] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [Actions#convention-default#]

To use your own package (default) you can either:

- use [ParentPackage annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-ParentPackageannotation)
- define struts.convention.default.parent.package in struts.xml

Comment: Thank you so much Lukasz Lenart i spent a lot of time trying to resolve it. I've used second option. Now i wonder why the plugin docs doesn't say anything about it so could you explain me why is necessary to add a parent package? P.D. you've killed two birds with one stone my interceptor works too n_n

Comment: @Marisolpatito The convention docs list the default parent package as `"convention-default"` and describe using the `@ParentPackage` annotation to change it. The error message is pretty explicit in describing the error as an unknown type in the package. If you can sum up the documentation change that would clarify this in a better way someone will update the docs.